# React-Native cross-platform example write once and use anywhere or DRY?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, react-native, cross-platform

I am very new to React-Native and love it so far.  Really great technology and very impressive tooling.  I would like to propose it for use in my company.

However ... react-native examples demoing code-sharing btw Android and IOS platform are simply nowhere to find???  All I have found after 3-4 weeks looking into it is few excellent but **only** IOS examples.  Below, are just few examples of articles lacking this.  Although some of them claim in their title to cover both, they cover only IOS:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/165140/react-native-tutorial-building-ios-android-apps-javascript

https://mentormate.com/blog/react-native-components/

http://www.andevcon.com/news/take-a-crack-at-react-native-with-kyle-banks

https://appendto.com/2016/11/build-a-coffee-finder-app-with-react-native-and-the-yelp-api/

https://reactjs.co/react-native-convention/

https://www.lullabot.com/articles/build-native-ios-and-android-apps-with-react-native

https://code.facebook.com/posts/1189117404435352/react-native-for-android-how-we-built-the-first-cross-platform-react-native-app/

https://medium.com/@MentorMate/best-practices-for-building-an-app-with-react-native-components-7dee3b2b010f

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-dictionary-app-using-react-native-for-android--cms-24969

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html

... , this list could continue on and on but it should be enough to demonstrate the lack of good resources I'm talking about.

I understand react-native is cross platform in terms that you can write code for both Android and IOS, that is all clear and great.

But is it sharing the code? In other words, is it DRY?  From what I see, it is write once for each platform rather than write once for all platforms.  Again, I understand some Views (but not all) are platform specific but again, there is no example to show even that on both Android and IOS in the same project.

Where is a non-hello-world (real life) example to clearly demonstrates and teaches how to do that?  React native used to have it in version 0.20 or so but it was removed and replaced with a HelloWorld example?  Seriously @Facebook???

As per links above, lots of React-Native articles out-there are titled to cover both platforms but then they only talk about IOS without even mentioning any other platform?  Very few talk about Android only, again, not even touching other platform in the same project.  ... and lots of them are outdated!

I understand that the technology is very new (and very good from what I have seen so far, I really love it).

But assuming I have to propose React-Native as a next-gen platform to a company, I do not see any convincing cross-platform, code-sharing examples demoing this for both Android, IOS (UWP??) that I could help me learn, understand, build, and demo an example for that proposal.

**I am not looking for chatty comments or links to courses but rather examples to show how to do this in more than just CRNA generated HelloWorld app.**

Comment: amazing!  people marking this question to close ... so, how is this helpful please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer here https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/build-react-native-retrofitting-ios-app-to-android-gsf5uyl1q in the very 1st paragraph and it is exactly what I have been trying to get RN/Facebook answer but they ignored the question all the time.

Very disappointing!

So, ReactNative is not "build-once-use-everywhere" but rather "learn-once-use-everywhere" meaning lots of code duplication.  And by everywhere, they mostly mean Android and IOS although the examples out-there are mainly IOS.  If they cover both platforms, then it is with almost no code sharing but lots of code-duplication.

Although, RN claims they can achieve up to 90% of code sharing, that is not demonstrated anywhere that I could find.  Documentation is very shallow in touching anything let alone topic of code-sharing and the tutorial provided by RN is a HelloWorld, ... yes, seriously.  Sad!  Although they used to have a better tutorial in older version (like 0.20 or so).

In terms of recommending RN to a company as a next-gen platform, I see few issues

- concerning patent license, no answers no explanations, very obscure and concerning for a company that would consider moving to this, I'd rather say open-source under quotation marks. Hopefully this will change as I see it as a mayor showstopper for anyone considering adapting this technology.  **I would say this is no more applicable as FB made react-native licensed using MIT as per https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/16079**
- documentation that is very basic without giving depth of explanation.  For example, this is react-native site with demo sample to demonstrate code-sharing cross-platform nature (I warn you, it is a HelloWorld example) https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html
- React Native Community facebook page which is the page where you are supposed to find help and ask question as per react-native site will simply block you if you bring this topic on and will not let you in
- even here on SO, questions like this (after extremely thorough and time consuming research) will earn you only downgrades and zero answers or even attempts
- examples lack clarity and depth of explanation, it seem like whole community follow one pattern, copy / paste demonstrating code-duplication rather than code-sharing
- Most examples cover (to most basic extent) only IOS although most claim cross-platform nature on both Android and IOS with Android being  mentioned in the title only and the body covering only IOS
- Impossible to ask for help on react-native site
- Impossible to suggest improvement on react-native site other than create pull request.  In other words, they want you to work for them for free
- The framework is cross-platform, that is great but it is more of a copy/paste (copy from IOS into Android, then modify what needs modification) rather than code-sharing strategy.  Every example I was able to find and it took me a month, was a violation of DRY principle in its best form

Although I mentioned things that bothered me at most during my research, I have to say that I hope this technology will thrive and become clear open source platform in future.  I really like it and hope someone at @Facebook / @ReactNative will consider these suggestions, or at least provide improvements in the documentation, examples, access to community, place to ask questions and get help, clear licensing, ... all of which I was not able to get after spending a month researching RN.

Perhaps the technology is still not mature enough, which makes sense, it is very new.

Would I recommend it?

- To developers yes, definitely.  I really like it myself and will spend more time studying it.
- To a company?  Not really for the reason explained above.

**UPDATES - Getting Better :):**

... and to add my 2c to anyone who faced the same problem and contribute to community (at least in terms of finding tutorials that talk about both IOS and Android), I will keep posting links I have managed to find so far:

- https://differential.com/insights/sharing-code-between-android-and-ios-in-react-native/ is very basic example.  Not really code sharing but rather code duplication but at least something
- https://www.codementor.io/vijayst/build-react-native-retrofitting-ios-app-to-android-gsf5uyl1q, also more of a code copying rather than code sharing but hey... going somewhere
- https://hackernoon.com/getting-started-with-react-navigation-the-navigation-solution-for-react-native-ea3f4bd786a4 another good one

This document explains that RN philosophy is "learn once, write anywhere" rather than "write once, run anywhere"  http://makeitopen.com/tutorials/building-the-f8-app/design/